# Mass Modification of Questions (bumping)

Tags: discussion

What should we do if someone modifies a bunch of their questions in order to bump them onto the first page again?

Comment: I think about half those bumps were on answers. Still it is a good idea to have a policy on this.

Comment: Why is this always a bad thing, (and so would require some kind of pre-decided treatment)?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I think one problem which arises is that newer questions (which have yet to be answered) end up buried and may not get answered because of it.

Answer (score 4):

if the edits are not at all constructive, flag one of the posts for moderator attention, and describe what's going on.

If they are constructive, then you could post a polite comment asking them to slow down so that they don't swamp the front page.

Comment: A good process, However,  my understanding is that the SE system doesn't actually allow private messages to users.

Comment: @BKay I'm not sure which of my two sentences you're referring to, so if (1) a flag for moderator attention does include a private message to the moderators; if (2) the polite comment I propose would be public, not private

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if I am the implicit target of this question (and I really don't take it personally if I am), but I clearly have, from time to time, edited a bunch of my old questions/answers, which made them bump onto the first page again.

The reason I sometimes edit my old questions/answers is I am not a great writer.  I usually leave typos and grammatical errors in my posts (sometimes embarrassing ones).

Every now and then, when I have time, I like to go over old posts of mine to correct as many typos as I can.

I believe there is a value-added for the site to me improving the wording, grammar and spelling of these old posts. But I've noticed that it bumps the posts back onto the first page, and I agree that this is disruptive of the site's question flow as it makes new questions disappear quicker from the first page.

Any suggestions on how to get the best of both worlds (i.e. the ability to improve past posts without swamping the first page) would be much welcome. I'd be happy to follow them.

**One suggestion** : is there a way to ask SE to only bump edited posts to the first page after *substantial* edits, say only when more than x-characters were changed?

(I have no problem either with refraining from these edits if the community deems them too disruptive and there is no way to prevent first page bumping.)